# Ordering the records

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, sql-order-by

I am trying to order the records in below order

1) Special Characters
2) Only Numbers
3) Alphabetic / Alphanumeric

Records

```
G1
G10
G19
123
87
!@#$
G5
G25
G9
```

Expected Output:

```
!@#$
87
123
G1
G5
G9
G10
G19
G25
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/662f5/6)

Can anyone please help on this.

I have tried `SUBSTRING(name FROM '^(.*?)( \\d+)?$')`

Comment: Does Postgresql support collations with numeric sorting?

Comment: yes, I guess it supports

Comment: If it does, do something like `ORDER BY Records COLLATE numericcollation`. (You may need to treat specials characters separately...)

Comment: how are you defining the order of special characters? would !@#$ come before @#!$ ? what is the logic. Also what about numbers? first digit numerical? smallest to largest? And the letters would it be G1, G2, G3 etc or would it be G1, G12, G23, G3, G45

Comment: for that matter, I haven't considered the special characters ordering, but if we are comparing it with alphabets / numbers / alphanumeric, then special characters should be in first place

Comment: I'm almost there see try this `select * 
from test 
order by  substring(name FROM '^[0-9]*$'),substring(name FROM '[0-9]+')::int`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to match the order by criteria

```
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY substring(NAME FROM '[$&+,:;=?@#|]') -- To get special character
        ,substring(NAME FROM '^[0-9]*$')::INT -- To get only integer from a value(87 and 123)
        ,substring(NAME FROM '[0-9]+')::INT   -- To get integer from a value (10 from G10)
```

---

[***SQLFIDDLE-Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e5a23/2/1)